# Need to use python variable in mysql query through os.system()

Tags: python, mysql, os.system

```
ID="VC002538"
mysql -u xxxxx --password=xxxxx -e "SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='$ID'"
```

sample

Above query I will execute in Linux shell prompt, it executed successfully with below output

```
+------+
| id   |
+------+
| 1140 |
+------+
```

But when do the same in python with os.system() method 
I am not getting any output

```
ID="VC002538"

os.system('mysql -u xxxxx --password=xxxxx -e "SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='ID'" sample')
```

but when I tried with ID value directly

```
os.system('mysql -u xxxxx --password=xxxxx -e "SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='\VC002538\'" sample')
```

This is working

Please let me know how to use the variable in `os.system()` in sql query

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, what Mysql sees is this query:

```
SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='ID'
```

You need to construct a string using the variable `ID`, for example like this:

```
"SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='%s'" % ID
```

or

```
"SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='" + ID + "'"
```

or

```
"SELECT orderid FROM Pran_order_detail WHERE orderid='{}'".format(ID)
```

You can find more information by googling "python string formatting".